# Laravel UTF-8 Problems

Tags: php, laravel-5

When ill try to return some Objects from my Database with special Chars, like "ä", "ö" or something like that, ill found out that my values not being correct returned by laravel.

The database is mysql, and i using here in database.php:

```
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

When ill return some values, ill use:

```
    return response()->json($response, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

But i am always getting encoding problems, like **"BegrÃ¼ndung:"**

In my database all values are correct saved with that special chars, so it should be a ORM problem?

Comment: How do exactly did you get that string? Does the output target have the properly set `UTF-8` as encoding?

Comment: When ill check the JSON Response in the Browser/App.

Comment: The Content-Type is text/json - so it should not be a local UTF-8 meta tag problem.

Comment: Are you sure? The `Ã¼` is exactly `ó` character when displayed in a single byte encoding. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f3/index.htm

Comment: Already found a solution from num8er. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
return response()
    ->json($response, 200, ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: @derdida I told you :-)

Comment: So the problem was only an encoding problem by the header - thought that should be something different ;) Thanks for your help mates!